# viewing user reputation and moderator by country

Tags: support

Is is possible to view users by reputation for a particular country. For example I want to see users in India with their reputation. Is that possible?

Comment: Here **[Top users from India](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81789/top-indian-users-in-stackoverflow)**

Answer (score 4):

You can't search for users per country using the website itself.

You could use SEDE, but that is a long shot since the data isn't normalized (location is a free field, so you can't be certain if an user filled it correctly).

Also see my [related answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253728/245360).